# intellij idea ignoring MaxPermSize run parameter

Tags: java, intellij-idea

It seems something strange happening with my intllij idea. I'm trying to launch project in intellij and constantly getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` regardless the value I set for -XX:MaxPermSize (tried from 256 to 4096, no effect). It seems intellij doesn't use it at all. Application get OutOfMemory exception when java process acquares approximately 700mb of memory. Just to compare: this project gets launched in eclipse and in the end it consumes about 4gb of memory.

Is there a bug regarding this or I'm the only who faces this issue? Could somebody, please, point me at my mistakes?

**ADDITION**
Content of my idea64.exe.vmoptions

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=500m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```

Comment: Where do you set the parameter?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, In VM options of launch configuration. I do it like this: `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Comment: So `idea.exe.vmoptions` or `idea64.exe.vmoptions` ? Could you post the file content in the question please.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, I wonder if it have something to do with launching applications in idea, not idea itself? However, update question with content of my `idea64.exe.vmoptions`.

Comment: Are you running **idea64.exe**? It could be a bug, look into IntelliJ log and if there is a stacktrace with OOM then report it, if not, then start IntelliJ with **idea.bat** and you should see it there...

Comment: I made some investigation with help of jet brains developers and it seems to be idea bug or some project misconfiguration which we were unable to identify.